# An issue with some JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I'm a beginner in JavaScript, and I have an issue running this script:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>some tests with javascript</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="demo">Here I'm testing some code with javascript </p>
        <script >
            function myFunction() {
                x = document.getELementById("demo");
                x.innerHTML = "Hi! my content has been changed ! ^^";
            }
        </script>
        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">click me !</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why is the content of the demo element not changing after I click the button?

Comment: `getELementById` `->` `getElementById`: Lower case `l`. [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820), the browser tells you about such errors.

Comment: Ah thank you @FelixKling , I didn't pay attention to the fact that Javascript is case sensitive, put your comment as an answer so that I check it as the answer :)

Comment: Questions like this get usually closed since it's a typographic error which isn't going to be of much use to other people. But as long as you got your issue resolved, it severed its purpose ;)

Comment: i think your issue has been solved. Try jQuery. it is easier to write and read. // like. $('#elementID').html('your new text');

Comment: @Riad: vanilla javascript is no problem I think. Why to load a library just for this?

Comment: @FelixKling Ok thank you for information. I can't find the link for the plugin you gave me in the first comment :)

Comment: @Sergio: Ok, actually not for this.... but he will not do this only thing i guess..!

Comment: @Riad, still. No browser issue here as far as I can see... Better to advise not use inline script then to advise jQuery.

Comment: @Riad telling OP to introduce some bloated and slow library (especially for OPs taks) is terrible advice

Comment: It's not a plugin. Chrome, Firefox and IE have built-in developer tools. (Opera probably too)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a spelling error. Instead of:

```
.getELementById    //Here you have L with uppercase, has to be lowercase
```

do this

```
.getElementById    //Check the 'l'
```

Cheers

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2bz6V/)

Answer (score 1):

Change

`x = document.getELementById("demo");`

into

`x = document.getElementById("demo");`

Comment: why a negative marking in this answer..!!??

Comment: Omri Aharon... welcome :)